# Modify the android source code so that it allows only those applications to be installed which are developed by me

Tags: android

I am working with a client on one of their ideas. The idea requires the android source code to be modified in such a way that it only runs applications which are developed by us and blocks applications from all other developers. Is it possible to do this?

Only applications which we develop for our custom android build will be installed and applications from play store or other developers won't be installed. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible... just modify the system to only start applications signed by your identity. You'll need your public key baked into the framework.

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid. But even more curious: I wonder who will keep me from making use of a public key? What about reverse engineering? And another question: would the "... for work" concept be useful in this context?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As i don't know much about signing applications, so there are a couple of things i need to ask:

1. I've read that you create a keystore that contains a set of private keys. Can you use the same keystore or other private/public keys for multiple apps?

2. In the part where android checks the signatures while installing the app, we put a condition that if the keys are equal to the keys which we have defined, then install the application otherwise discard it and exit the installation process. Is this the way to approach this problem?